# Unable to access on host machine an angular app that is run in docker container

Tags: angular, docker

I am trying to serve an angular (SSR) application in development mode  in Docker and accessing it on a host machine.
But I am unable to access the application.
When I visit `http://localhost:4200/` - I get unable to access webpage error.
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:21.6.1-alpine3.19
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i --legacy-peer-deps
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Executed commands:

```
docker build -t testapp .
docker run -d -p 4200:4200 testapp
```

Running containers:

```
apower ~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
9f81d9629adb   testapp   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp   interesting_kepler
```

(note 0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp)

Docker container logs:

```
2024-02-08 22:34:42 
2024-02-08 22:34:42 > important_day-frontend@0.0.0 start
2024-02-08 22:34:42 > ng serve
2024-02-08 22:34:42 
2024-02-08 22:34:42 Node.js version v21.6.1 detected.
2024-02-08 22:34:42 Odd numbered Node.js versions will not enter LTS status and should not be used for production. For more information, please see https://nodejs.org/en/about/previous-releases/.
2024-02-08 22:34:44 - Building...
2024-02-08 22:34:44 
2024-02-08 22:34:55 
2024-02-08 22:34:55 Initial Chunk Files | Names              |  Raw Size
2024-02-08 22:34:55 polyfills.js        | polyfills          |  83.46 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 styles.css          | styles             |  49.53 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 main.js             | main               |  36.47 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-YYT7ILY5.js   | -                  |  23.16 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-BSM7ZHVN.js   | -                  |   5.50 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-6OTDBEQJ.js   | -                  |   2.71 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-SHAOKUVO.js   | -                  | 938 bytes |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 
2024-02-08 22:34:55                     | Initial Total      | 201.74 kB
2024-02-08 22:34:55 
2024-02-08 22:34:55 Lazy Chunk Files    | Names              |  Raw Size
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-RB2O73BU.js   | organize-component |  33.89 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-57SAREFX.js   | homepage-component |  24.65 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-ADUS5TSN.js   | page-component     |  24.52 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-PIQVPTGB.js   | -                  |  22.52 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-XNUFOG6T.js   | terms-component    |  22.19 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-OHRVTT7Q.js   | account-component  |  21.20 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-USAF6IDX.js   | back-component     |  16.89 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-I4Y6VYK3.js   | -                  |   7.57 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-7KKNKUNL.js   | -                  |   5.14 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-VVUS2U7Q.js   | -                  |   4.25 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 chunk-F2ON6633.js   | -                  |   3.27 kB |
2024-02-08 22:34:55 
2024-02-08 22:34:55 Application bundle generation complete. [10.589 seconds]
2024-02-08 22:34:55 Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...
2024-02-08 22:34:55   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:4200/
```

Comment: Where your `package.json` file specifies `ng serve`, it needs to say `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: yes, I did it already and ti helped. sleepless night. tnx